# How to better initialize objects in factory?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have following case: there is a factory which returns instances of Function interface:

```java
public class RatingTableRowModifierFactory
{
  @Autowired
  private PlanSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier planSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier;
  @Autowired
  private CompositeBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier compositeBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier;
  @Autowired
  private RafRatingTableRowModifier rafTableRowModifier;

  public Function<RowBean, RowBean> getRowModifierInstance(.... input)
  {
    switch (ratingType)
    {
      case AGE:
        return planSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier;
      case COMPOSITE_AGE:
        return planSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier
          .andThen(compositeBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier)
          .andThen(rafTableRowModifier);
      default:
        return new EmptyRatingTableRowModifier();
    }
  }
}
```

The main issue in my approach is that each specific instance of RowModifier has to accept some additional parameters in order to correctly execute *apply* method. For example I need to pass **algorithm id** parameter into the **planSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier** and **quote id** into the **rafTableRowModifier**. I can't add these arguments inside the **RowBean** object and the only place where I can add them is **getRowModifierInstance** method. Please let me know if it's ok or not? As for me, it looks bad because if number of *modifiers* will grow then number of method parameters might also grow which is bad from my opinion... Please help me to understand how to avoid that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you maybe give the Modifiers a query whether they apply for a specific RatingType? Then you could iterator through the available modifiers in a loop and compose depending on the modifier is applicable to the current RatingType.

Comment: The main issue is that before calling `planSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier` I need to make some `initialization` with for example some quote id and I don't know where it would be better to put this initialization.

Comment: What I mean is something like `Function<RB,RB> result = new EmptyMod(); for (RatingType ratingType : RatingType.values()) { for (Modifier mod : modifierList) { if mod.isApplicableTo(ratingType) { result = result.andThen(mod); }}}; return result;`

Comment: the main problem for me is to add some initialization logic before creating modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your specific situation, but I guess that in upper layer you know how and which parameter you want to pass for rating type. If you want to stay in this approach, to avoid passing nulls, you can add second parameter which will be `Map<enum, Object>`:

```
enum ModifiersEnum {
    COMPOSITE_BENEFITS_TABLE_ROW, 
    TABLE_ROW;
}

public Function<RowBean, RowBean> getRowModifierInstance(ModifiersEnum ratingType, Map<ModifiersEnum, Object> parameters) {
    switch (ratingType)
    {
      case AGE:
        return planSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier;
      case COMPOSITE_AGE:
        return planSpecificBenefitsRatingTableRowModifier
          .andThen(parameters.get(ModifiersEnum.COMPOSITE_BENEFITS_TABLE_ROW))
          .andThen(parameters.get(ModifiersEnum.TABLE_ROW));
      default:
        return new EmptyRatingTableRowModifier();
    }
}
```

As I said I don't know how you invoke this factory pattern, but in this situation you can pass generic parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your response. At the end I decided not to use factory here and initialized each object separately in place where it's needed.